# Personal notebook feature for StackExchange?

Tags: feature-request, participation, user-interface

I'm curious if there is any effort to implement a "personal notebook" feature in StackExchange? This would be a feature of an individual account, similar to the current question-asking interface, where one can write up notes, ideas, and other personal details about the various Math, Stats, Code, and other features that Stack Exchange offers, and have them available as a personal resource (or even public, if one chooses to make them available). Questions that one asks could then be associated with these, if desired, to better organize one's thoughts as ideas and understandings are formed.

StackExchange offers a nice typeset interface with its LaTeX (and other) support that allows for writing up ideas, and having a separate notebook area of an account where one can use these tools to explore ideas would be exceptionally useful as folks like myself explore these technical fields and ask questions.

Just as with questions, as one writes about a topic for his or her notes, StackExchange could offer suggestions for similar topics that could be explored, linked to, and otherwise interacted with.

Such a feature could contribute to collaboration and sharing among friends and colleagues, or simply be a library of one's personal ideas that can be accessed from anywhere. I know I'd use it extensively, and am wondering if others also see use in it?

Comment: I'm not aware of any such proposed feature, but I bet it's been asked about before -- it might be useful to have such facilities from a variety of viewpoints (a personal sandbox would be very handy). The thing to do is search on meta.stackexchange for posts on this kind of things, and if you don't find any, to post a feature request. The features of such a notebook would presumably vary from SE site to SE site. (e.g. only a few sites have MathJax)

Comment: This better fits for Meta-meta, as @Glen_b suggested. As about the functionality, I don't think it fits the SE framework. SE is problem-focused rather then social networking site, so it is not really user-focused, while this kind of notebook would in fact be some kind of "blog" - blogs are *not* problem-focused. Also the idea of Q&A site is *not* to share personal thoughts and ideas, so this kind of subjective page does not fit it.